# Sum of Counts from successive dates

Tags: mysql, date, count, sum

I need to get the total number of an item for every month.

So far, with the following code :

```
Select Count(mpay_collector_company.id) As `Number of Collector Companies`,
  Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As Month,
  Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As Year
From mpay_collector_company
Group By Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at),
  Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at)
```

I have the following response :

```
#|Year|Month
------------
5|2014|11
3|2014|12
3|2015|1
7|2015|2
6|2015|3
2|2015|4
5|2015|6
1|2015|7
```

And instead of the number for each month I'd like to have the sum from the beginning for each month, which would be something like this :

```
Sum|Year|Month
--------------
  5|2014|11
  8|2014|12
 11|2015|1
 18|2015|2
 24|2015|3
 26|2015|4
 31|2015|6
 32|2015|7
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :** This request will be implemented as a view, so sub-requests are pretty much a no-go :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
Select Count(distinct previous_mpay_collector_company.id)+ Count(distinct mpay_collector_company.id) As `Number of Collector Companies`,
       Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As Month,
       Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As Year
From mpay_collector_company
  Left Join mpay_collector_company previous_mpay_collector_company
    On   Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) > Year(previous_mpay_collector_company.created_at)
 OR (Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) > Month(previous_mpay_collector_company.created_at)
         And  Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) >= Year(previous_mpay_collector_company.created_at))
  And previous_mpay_collector_company.id <> mpay_collector_company.id
Group By Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at),
Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at);
```

The trick would be self joining to all of the previous months and counting from the joined table.

Comment: I'm getting pretty silly results in the count, however I like that solution because I need to implement this as a view so sub-requests are not really a good thing for that :p

Comment: Alright, give me a second, I will create some test data.

Comment: That query got a little out of hand, but I've edited my answer after plugging in some test data.

Comment: BTW, if you're worried about performance, then joining over functions is a no-no since MySQL won't be able to work with indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll get back to you on Monday. I have everything at work and I just came back home for a relaxing weekend ^^'

Comment: Confirmed, works like a charm and I can export it as a view. Kudos !

Comment: @Gyoo When I tested this query the result seems to be nowhere near the desired result. Is it really what you want? See this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972ad/12 Specifically it doesn't seem to do any running sum at all.

Comment: @jpw Well interestingly enough I ran this query on my local mysql and it returned the right result... I totally see that the sqlfiddle does not, but why there is such a difference is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Gyoo Ok. Good that it worked for you then :) I was just confused as the fiddle showed something that didn't look right. Maybe the fiddle was set up incorrectly.

Comment: FWIW - The logic for the join condition on this query ended up being a lot more complicated than I had originally planned, and like I said earlier, there isn't really a performance improvement with the self join since we're joining on derived values.  If @jpw is confident in his or her solution, then it might be a safer choice than mine since it's a little more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can first select distinct year.months and then check count for each value

```
select year,month , 
    ( SELECT count(*) FROM mpay_collector_company WHERE 
        Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) <= temp1.year 
        AND 
        Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) <= temp1.month 
    )
from (
Select DISTINCT 
    Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As month,
    Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As year
From mpay_collector_company 
) as temp1
ORDER BY year,month
```

if you want to "reset" for each year , just change comparison to EQUAL between years and thats it

```
select year,month , 
    ( SELECT count(*) FROM mpay_collector_company WHERE 
        Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) = temp1.year 
        AND 
        Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) <= temp1.month 
    )
from (
Select DISTINCT 
    Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As month,
    Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at) As year
From mpay_collector_company 
) as temp1
ORDER BY year,month
```

Comment: That is a very good start, thank you about that !
However, the results are summed for 2014 and then reset for 2015, which means I get (2014)5->8->(2015)3->10->16... instead of (2014)5->8->(2015)11->18->24...

Comment: I have updated my answer for you , with "reset" query

Answer (score 0):

Using a correlated subquery to count the number of rows with a date before the current should work too:

```
Select 
  Count(id) As "Number of Collector Companies",
  Month(created_at) As Month,
  Year(created_at) As Year,
  (
    Select Count(*) 
    From mpay_collector_company 
    Where EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from created_at) <= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from m.created_at)     
  ) as running_count
From mpay_collector_company m
Group By Year(created_at), Month(created_at);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972ad/6) showing it in action

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select 
(Select Sum(Count(Z.id)) FROM mpay_collector_company z 
where  z.created_at <= A.created_at) as '#', 
  Month(A.created_at) As Month,
  Year(A.created_at) As Year
From mpay_collector_company A
Group By Month(mpay_collector_company.created_at),
  Year(mpay_collector_company.created_at)
```

This should do it for ya,